# ¿Que tipo de variable es y como se llama una variable con los dos puntos al final?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo el siguiente servicio

```
class Person
  def initialize(nationality: 'the world')
    @nationality = nationality
  end
  def is_from
    @nationality
  end
end
```

Lo instancio como debe ser:

```
rafael = Person.new
rafael.is_from # The world
```

Otra forma de instanciarlo es:

```
kevin = Person.new(nationality: 'USA')
kevin.is_from # USA
```

En la linea donde se inicializa el servicio está la variable `nationality:`

Las preguntas que tengo son las siguientes:

¿Que tipo de variable es esa con los dos puntos al final?

¿Cómo se llama ese tipo de variable con los puntos al final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos son [keywords](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), que sirven para manejar hashes de una manera más simple, accediendo directamente al key. Al final, lo que pasas como argumento es un hash de toda la vida:

```rb
params = {nationality: 'USA'}
kevin = Person.new(params)
```

En la definición del inicializador, podrías llamar a:

```rb
  def initialize(args = {})
    @nationality = args[:nationality] || 'the world'
  end
```

y sería exactamente lo mismo a la definición que compartes con keywords, pero claramente esta última es mucho mas verbosa.
Por último, puedes invocarlo además como:

```rb
def initialize(nationality:)
```

para lo cual será obligatorio que uses un hash con esa clave o te arrojará un error:

```rb
Person.new(nationality: 'Chile') # => #<Person:0x00007fe20a9d3458 @nationality="Chile">
Person.new(country: 'Chile') # (irb):2:in `initialize': missing keyword: :nationality (ArgumentError)
Person.new # (irb):2:in `initialize': missing keyword: :nationality (ArgumentError)
```